# How to add a .vbproj file to an existing project inside a solution in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions

I have an existing VB.Net project inside a solution that has been in use for 10 years. It is large, and recreating it is not an option. We would like to add a Unit Testing project to test it with, but it needs to have a .vbproj file in order to reference it from the Unit Testing project.

The existing project does not have a .vbproj file. Apparently, it was created as a "New Website" and a .vbproj file was never created. Is there a way to add this .vbproj file to the existing Project, or another way to reference it from the Unit Test?

Comment: If it's a web site then it's not a project so it has no project file.  If you want a project then you have no choice but to create a new project.  You can then import pages from the existing web site using Add -> Existing Item.  If you don't want to do that then you're out of luck.  Wanting something to be possible doesn't make it possible.

Comment: ok. If I can't create a project file, is there another way to reference it from a Unit Test?